# Looks like I encountered an error (error #404) in mautic

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-5.6, mautic

recently install mautic 2.8.1, after setup api ,authorized it in auth2, after so many try it only gives output:

> Looks like I encountered an error (error #404). If I do it again,
>   please report me to the system administrator!

Do you have any idea, about this how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried the system administrator?

Comment: yeah, already a system administrator.

Comment: Kidding, please put in some code, ex: how have you installed the addon. Otherwise we are in the dark

Answer (score 4):

Clearing Mautic's cache usually solves this. Run `rm -rf app/cache/prod/*` in the Mautic root directory.

Another issue may be wrong URL. Double check it doesn't have two slashes or something like it. I also saw that someone tried to access `https://some.mautic/api` That endpoint does not exist. But `https://some.mautic/api/contacts` does.

Update: Since Mautic 3 the cache directory was moved to `bin/cache`.

Comment: John, what if my Mautic installation doesn't have an `app/cache` directory? I've been stuck unable to use Mautic because although it loads and lets me create contacts and whatnot through the dashboard, I cannot connect via the API. I always get "Looks like I encountered an error (error #404). If I do it again, please report me to the system administrator!" My credentials seem to work because if I change the credentials at all, I get "Authorization denied, invalid credentials." So I don't know why `https://some.mautic/api/contacts` & all other endpoints produce 404 errors. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oddly, there *was* an `app/cache` directory, but it wasn't visible on my host Windows 10 machine, on which I'm running a Laravel Homestead Vagrant VM, which is where Mautic is installed. I noticed that when I SSHed into the Vagrant machine, I saw the `cache` directory and deleted it. Then the API worked (except the `search` param of https://developer.mautic.org/?json#list-contacts doesn't work, but that's an unrelated bug).